# Self-hosted SQL database (LocalDB) with UWP application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, uwp, localdb

I have a UWP application working with a SQL database that will be published to the Microsoft Store soon. As part of a test in its free version, I'd like to enable app user to create a kind of self-hosted database. Self-hosted means I don't user to need to install anything else than the app itself.

**Expected behavior**

The user clicks on a button (when the UWP app starts) and the LocalDB instance is started with an attached database. The user connects to this database from the app then!

**Constraints**

- the client machine does not have LocalDB or SQLExpress installed
- it cannot be another database system (as the base is quiet complexe, I can't maintain different systems for the same app), I know SQLite is designed for that but it does not suit my needs

**Questions**

- How can I create a package starting a LocalDB instance with a specific database?
- Can this package be integrated into the UWP app?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I found thousand of topics on the web but only for cases with LocalDB is already installed on the client machine.

Comment: I aggree. SQLite is not a good solution for high-loading local db models for UWP scanarios. Personnaly I'd like to use Local DB I will try it anyway. If not then SQL Express is the uniqe solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually need a permanent data store, I would suggest that you use dependency injection for your database connectivity and you then simply substitute say SQLite for your remote SQL interaction when running in demonstration mode. You'll need to include a Nuget package for your app in this case.

If you don't need a permanent data store e.g. you wish to retain data between power cycles or application start cycles, then you load a mock database that just runs in ram e.g. using simple class objects and lists instead of actual database tables.

In both cases you can enable an initialisation function that populates your data on application start.

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is a demo you can use a datasets in the project
the data in it can be exported into XML or loaded from it
then all you need is to ship some boilerplate data that was generated using the app and exported in the XML format

user clicks load and you load the XML file into the datasets and update the UI
you can use the export functions to overwrite the XML file if you wanna add the persistence functionality